# Как подключить .pro библиотеку в Qt проект

Tags: qt, qt5, библиотеки

Есть библиотека: [Qt-AES](https://github.com/bricke/Qt-AES)
Она содержит только `.pro` файл (нет `.pri` файла)
Положил данную библиотеку в директория AES в корне проекта.
А вот как привязать эту библиотеку в `qmake` - непонятно.
Не подскажите - как подключаются подобные библиотеки?

Answer (score 0):

а в чем собственно проблема? открываете .pro в qtcreator и компилируете...

Или из командной строки (на примере mingw):

> mingw32-make release

Если надо использовать в своем проекте, то просто подключаете .h и .cpp в свой проект и используете класс QAESEncryption

PS: не понятно только зачем такой велосипед, если AES уже давно реализован в процессорах на аппаратном уровне

Comment: Tatarincev Спасибо! Порой очевидное не совсем очевидно, когда зациклился) Понимаю, что вопрос не совсем по теме - а можно поподробнее, как использовать AES на аппаратном уровне